# Determine data signal strength

Tags: android

I know that it's possible to determine the data connection type (WIFI/or cellular) through Android, but is it possible to determine the cellular connection type and strength?

I have an app that downloads some images and I have found that on GPRS or on 3G with weak signal that this download process slows up the app unacceptably. What I want to do is say that if you have either WIFI or a strong and fast data connection then download; otherwise display a default placeholder image.

Any clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about not blocking the UI thread and running long running tasks in a background thread where they belong to?

Look up the reference on [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and the article on threading called [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

**Update:** Alright then lookup the reference page on [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) which does just what you want.

**Update2**: Just realized that you wanted to know about the signal strength. In that case you need to lookup the [SignalStrength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) class.

Comment: I have done all of that - it's still just a painfully slow thing on a poor data connection

Comment: No it doesn't. It might tell me what kind of connection but, as far as I can see, it doesn't give any information about the signal strength...

Comment: Re: Update 2: Thanks - that's helpful.

Comment: SignalStrength doesn't seem to relate to data signal strength... I have a Phonestatelistener with onSignalStrengthChanged() implemented and it simply doesn't seem to be being called...

Comment: @Paul Hunnisett: Would you please elaborate what you mean by _data signal strength_? I think your understanding of it is a bit flawed.

Comment: Quite possibly so - What I mean is the strength of the 3G/GPRS/etc. signal as opposed to the phone signal strength. Or are they exactly the same?

Comment: @Paul Hunnisett: As far as I know they are exactly the same signal wise. But I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3):

- Determining the radio technology (network type) is simple:

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

```
int nt = tm.getNetworkType();

    switch (nt) {
            case 1: return GPRS;
            case 2: return EDGE;
            case 3: return UMTS;
            case 8: return HSDPA;
            case 9: return HSUPA;
            case 10:return HSPA;
            default:return UNKNOWN;
            }
```

- If you want to estimate the download time you must mesure the bandwidth in Kbps by opening socket connection for example .. But that is too complicated! I suggest you to try to download the image in AsyncTask anyway and set a timer limit to say 5 seconds. If the download is not achived then stop the asynctask and display a default placeholder image.